# C++ self-registering factory, multi parameters constructors

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory, abstract-factory

I read [this](http://www.nirfriedman.com/2018/04/29/unforgettable-factory/) article about C++ factory class with a self registering capability of the concrete classes. Really like it, expecially the demangled name solution used as a key for the registered classes.

There is one main issue I would like to solve: **how can we modify the factory to be able to support concrete classes with different constructor parameters**?

```
// Dog and Cat both derive from Animal, but have different constructor parameters
class Dog : public Animal::Registrar<Dog> {
public:
  Dog(int param1, std::string param2) : m_x(param1) {}

  void makeNoise() { std::cerr << "Dog: " << m_x << "\n"; }

private:
  int m_x;
};

class Cat : public Animal::Registrar<Cat> {
public:
  Cat(bool param1) : m_flag(param1) {}

  void makeNoise() { std::cerr << "Cat: " << m_x << "\n"; }

private:
  bool m_flag;
};
```

I was thinking that maybe the parameter pack of `template <class Base, class... Args> class Factory` should be moved to the `template <class T> struct Registrar`, but I can't found a proper solution.

Full original code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cxxabi.h>

std::string demangle(const char *name) {

  int status = -4; // some arbitrary value to eliminate the compiler warning

  std::unique_ptr<char, void (*)(void *)> res{
      abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status), std::free};

  return (status == 0) ? res.get() : name;
}

template <class Base, class... Args> class Factory {
public:

  template <class ... T>
  static std::unique_ptr<Base> make(const std::string &s, T&&... args) {
      return data().at(s)(std::forward<T>(args)...);
  }

  template <class T> struct Registrar : Base {
    friend T;

    static bool registerT() {
      const auto name = demangle(typeid(T).name());
      Factory::data()[name] = [](Args... args) -> std::unique_ptr<Base> {
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      };
      return true;
    }
    static bool registered;

  private:
    Registrar() : Base(Key{}) { (void)registered; }
  };

  friend Base;

private:
  class Key {
    Key(){};
    template <class T> friend struct Registrar;
  };
  using FuncType = std::unique_ptr<Base> (*)(Args...);
  Factory() = default;

  static auto &data() {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, FuncType> s;
    return s;
  }
};

template <class Base, class... Args>
template <class T>
bool Factory<Base, Args...>::Registrar<T>::registered =
    Factory<Base, Args...>::Registrar<T>::registerT();

struct Animal : Factory<Animal, int> {
  Animal(Key) {}
  virtual void makeNoise() = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal::Registrar<Dog> {
public:
  Dog(int x) : m_x(x) {}

  void makeNoise() { std::cerr << "Dog: " << m_x << "\n"; }

private:
  int m_x;
};

class Cat : public Animal::Registrar<Cat> {
public:
  Cat(int x) : m_x(x) {}

  void makeNoise() { std::cerr << "Cat: " << m_x << "\n"; }

private:
  int m_x;
};

// Won't compile because of the private CRTP constructor
// class Spider : public Animal::Registrar<Cat> {
// public:
//     Spider(int x) : m_x(x) {}

//     void makeNoise() { std::cerr << "Spider: " << m_x << "\n"; }

// private:
//     int m_x;
// };

// Won't compile because of the pass key idiom
// class Zob : public Animal {
// public:
//     Zob(int x) : Animal({}), m_x(x) {}

//      void makeNoise() { std::cerr << "Zob: " << m_x << "\n"; }
//     std::unique_ptr<Animal> clone() const { return
//     std::make_unique<Zob>(*this); }

// private:
//      int m_x;

// };

// An example that shows that rvalues are handled correctly, and
// that this all works with move only types

struct Creature : Factory<Creature, std::unique_ptr<int>> {
    Creature(Key) {}
    virtual void makeNoise() = 0;
};

class Ghost : public Creature::Registrar<Ghost> {
public:
    Ghost(std::unique_ptr<int>&& x) : m_x(*x) {}

    void makeNoise() { std::cerr << "Ghost: " << m_x << "\n"; }

private:
    int m_x;
};

int main() {
  auto x = Animal::make("Dog", 3);
  auto y = Animal::make("Cat", 2);
  x->makeNoise();
  y->makeNoise();
  auto z = Creature::make("Ghost", std::make_unique<int>(4));
  z->makeNoise();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense. If you want to make dogs with one set of constructor parameters and cats with the other set of constructor parameters, build two factories.

Comment: That' not the point. If I have an Interface, I want to be able to declare derived classes with different constructors parameters.

Comment: How would you **use** your proposed multi-class multi-interface factory? Do you want to have `factory.make("cat", false)` and `factory.make("dog", 42, "bark")`? What would be the sense of it? Since you **statically know** that `42, "bark"` is the set of dog parameters and `false` is the set of cat parameters, there is no point in dispatching on a string type indicator ("dog", "cat"). It is almost like having `compute("pow", 2, 3)` and `compute("sqrt", 42)` instead of two different functions `pow` and `sqrt`.

Comment: You don't get it: the factory IS the interface, that's the purpose of that article. So I can have only 1 factory (1 interface) for multiple concrete classes, that could have different constructors.

Comment: "the factory IS the interface" You can use the word "interface" however you like of course, but that's not how I use it. To me, your factory is many unrelated interfaces lumped into one class for no reason. "I can have only 1 factory" Why? What kind of constraint is that? Is it a homework and the constraint is arbitrarily imposed on you?